# Pagination - Webmatrix/razor

Tags: razor, twitter-bootstrap, webmatrix

i have used Mike Brind's guide to set up pagination, which works a treat. I have also used bootstrap to create a better looking page navigation at the bottom of my page. Can you please let me know what i need to do so that the NEXT and PREV buttons work? i imagine it's be something like i+1 and i-1, but i've yet to figure it out. here's my code:

EDITED CODE:

```
//Paging

var pageSize = 6; 
var totalPages = 0; 
var count = 0;
var page = UrlData[0].IsInt() ? UrlData[0].AsInt() : 1;
var offset = (page -1) * pageSize;

var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");
var sql = "Select Count(*) From PropertyInfo ";
count = (int)db.QueryValue(sql);
totalPages = count/pageSize;        
if(count % pageSize > 0){
    totalPages += 1;
}
sql = "SELECT PropertyName, PropertyID, ResortName, NumBedrooms, NumBathrooms, NumSleeps, BriefDescription, PrimaryImage FROM PropertyInfo "+
           "Order By PropertyID OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS  ONLY;";

var result = db.Query(sql, offset, pageSize);

<!--Pagination Start-->
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
<ul>  
@{   
    if(page > 1){     
    <li><a href="/portfolio1/@(page-1)">Prev</a></li>
    }
    for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++){
    <li><a href="/portfolio1/@i">@i</a></li>
    }
    if(page > 1){
    <li><a href="/portfolio1/@(page + 1)">Next</a></li>
    }
}
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<!--Pagination Finish-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you only want a Next or Previous button to appear if there is a next or previous page to go to? If so, and assuming that you are keeping track of the current page number in a variable called page, this is how you can do it:

```
<!--Pagination Start-->
<div class="pagination pagination-large">
<ul>
   @if(page > 1){
       <li><a href="/portfolio1/@(page-1)">Prev</a></li>
   }
   for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++){
       <li><a href="/portfolio1/@i">@i</a></li>
   }
   if(page < totalPages){
       <li><a href="/portfolio1/@(page + 1)">Next</a></li>
   }
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<!--Pagination Finish-->
```

Comment: Ok, so i used ures, and it errored slightly, but i made a few modifications and got it semi-working using this code...

Comment: <!--Pagination Start-->
    <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <ul>  
    @{   
        if(page > 1){     
        <li><a href="/portfolio1/@(page-1)">Prev</a></li>
        }
        for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++){
        <li><a href="/portfolio1/@i">@i</a></li>
        }
        if(page > 1){
        <li><a href="/portfolio1/@(page + 1)">Next</a></li>
        }
    }
    </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!--Pagination Finish-->

Comment: actually, i'll just edit the code at the top of the page. The problem is, on page one, it doesn't show a previous or next links. If i click on page 2, the prev and next buttons are there and working fine. The other issue is, when i am on page 3 of 3 the next button is still there, and i can move to pages 4 and 5 and so on, even though no records exist there?

Comment: It won't show a Prev button on page 1. There is no page previous to page 1. If the next button appears on page 3, your totalPages variable is calculated incorrectly.

Comment: I mean, if the Next link shows on page 3 _and there is no page 4_, then your totalPages variable is incorrect...

Comment: It doesn't show a Prev OR Next button on page 1 (i understand that it shouldn't show prev, but it should show next? i've updated the code above to include variables

Comment: The last if block should test to see `if(page < totalPages)` like in my reply